# How does a spirit escape combat?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse, spirits, werewolf-the-apocalypse-2nd-edition

**How does a spirit escape combat (in the Penumbra without utilizing any specific escape Charms) in Werewolf: the Apocalypse?**

What action does it take, and when, what does it roll against what trait or target number, and what does it have to possibly evade (i.e. how might a standard garou opponent prevent its escape)?

It's the 2nd edition of W:tA mechanics that I'm primarily interested in, but any other would do as well. (Not The Forsaken, though, of course.)

Comment: @sevensideddie I see you've removed the W:tA specification from the titles of two Qs of mine. I have nothing against that and can guess and understand the reason behind it (even though skimming the front page is harder so). Could you please point me to the policy / meta which recommends this, though, just out of curiosity? (Haven't been round here for a while. :)) Thanks.

Comment: Sure! It's in the help pages on tags. It's the end of [this help article](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/tagging).

Answer (score 3):

I think I've finally found the answer - it was hidden in plain sight in the WWtA 2nd edition core rulebook, on page 239, under "Pursuit in the Umbra".

I didn't look into that right away upon skimming the headings back before asking this Q because I didn't think I'd find *escaping* incorporated into that section as well.

"*When a spirit or a Garou tries to flee the battle, use the Pursuit rules on pg.213; the fleeing or chasing spirit rolls its Willpower (...)*" is how it begins, and it does cover the points I was looking for. (I'm not going to cite the section / rules here in their entirety to save space and for copyright reasons.)